# lookup previous date for same ID

Tags: excel

I want to write a formula that looks up the values from the latest date before the current date for the same ID field.

For example, I want to derive the PreVal column using the formula. is this possible in Excel?

```
 DATE       ID    Val   PreVal
2015-01-01   A    10     -
2015-01-02   B    15     -
2015-01-05   A    20    10
2015-01-06   A    15    20
2015-01-25   B    90    15
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date column is sorted, this should work

=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B3=B4),$C$2:C3)

You want $B$2:B3 to be the id column from the start till one row up from the one you are in, B4 is the ID of the row you're in and $C$2:C3 is the same range as $B$2:B3 but for the Val column.

Edit:

For non sorted ones, this one should work:

=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$6 < A4)/($B$2:$B$6=B4),$C$2:$C$6)

Edit2:

On second thought, it wont work, my bad.

Edit3:

Finaly found something that works. You must use an array formula (press the combination ctrl+shift+enter after entering the formula)

=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF($B$2:$B$6=IF(B2="A","B","A"),"",IF($A$2:$A$6>=A2,"",$A$2:$A$6))),$A$2:$C$6,3,0)

Answer (score 0):

Phew....found your answer....tough one.

Are you ok with array formulas? (Those are a little more complicated than normal formulas, it will only work if you pres **ctrl+shift+enter** after you type the formula)

You can use this formula (see comments below):

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF((B:B=B2) * (A:A<A2);A:A;0));IF((B:B=B2) * (A:A<A2);A:C;"-");3;FALSE)
```

- Do not forget to press `ctrl+shift+enter` to turn it into an array formula, it will get like this:

  ```
  {=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF((B:B=B2) * (A:A<A2);A:A;0));IF((B:B=B2) * (A:A<A2);A:C;"-");3;FALSE)}
  ```

It's terribly slow though....